# Model Mapper on different data type but same attribute name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, modelmapper

I have two classes

```
public class Transaction {
   private TransactionType paymentType;
   private TransactionStatus status;
```

```
public class TransactionDetails {
   private String paymentType;
   private String status;
```

when I use the Model Mapper to map the above classes

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<TransactionDetails>>(){}.getType();
        List<TransactionDetails> transactionDetailsList = modelMapper.map(transaction,listType);
```

Above **transaction** is the list of **Transaction objects** and trying to map to list of **TransactionDetails**.
After Mapping, I am receiving the response as

```
{
   "paymentType": "CASH",
   "status": null
}
```

Can anyone please tell, why modelMapper is able to map ONLY one variable and not the other one?